# Getting following error while running the code using "ng serve" command - "Unknown error: Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read"

Tags: angularjs, npm, frontend, angular-cli

Following is the command I am running :-

`C:\Users\Sainesh K\Desktop\angularp1\frontend> ng serve`

Here is the error which I am getting on the console:
**Unknown error:  Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, read**

[angular-cli installed but not running]

Answer (score 0):

Try to run project in other than C drive. In my case it solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked was, running an **antivirus security scan** on my computer. A malicious program was setting the node_modules inside C://users/name/AppData/roaming/npm to read only mode. Once that virus got removed, I Installed npm and angular cli again and it finally worked.